# How to run tests parallely using Testng?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, testng

I have scenario where I have to run 1 test before rest of the tests. The rest of the tests should be run in parallel.

For example: I have 4 Tests in one XML file. One test should run before the other 3 tests, and the 3 tests should run parallel.

Is there any possible way to do this using the [TestNG framework](http://testng.org/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `parallel="methods"` and have your four methods depend on the one you want to run first (ideally with a group dependency).

Comment: Thank you Cedric for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
One test should run before the other 3 tests
```

Annotate this test with @BeforeTest

`and the 3 tests should run parallel`.

Run them with @Test annotation and in the suite file give parallel = "methods"

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="3" verbose="1" name="My Test Suite" 
    skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" junit="false" parallel="methods" preserve-order="true" data-provider-thread-count="10" annotations="JDK">

    <test name = "my test" preserve-order="false">
        <classes>
            <class name ="com.mypackage.SampleClass"/>

            <methods>method2</methods>
            <methods>method3</methods>
            <methods>method4</methods>
        </classes>
    </test>
```